# Harmonic oscillator eq. for complex amplitude ---field quantization

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, quantum-optics

I am new to quantum optics and going through "Introductory quantum optics" by C. Gerry and P. Knight. In chapter 2  they are writing eq. (2.81), the harmonic oscillator eq. for complex amplitude A derived from eqs (2.60) and (2.61) which i am not able to derive. Can anybody help with mathematical steps involved to reach eq. (2.81) 
\begin{align}
  \nabla^2 \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}, t) - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t^2} &= 0 \tag{2.60} \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= 0 \tag{2.61} \\
\frac{d^2 A_{\mathbf{k}, s}}{dt^2} + \omega_k^2 A_{\mathbf{k}, s} &= 0 \tag{2.81}
\end{align}

Comment: They just seem to be expanding $A(\vec{r})$ in a orthonormal eigen basis of $\vec{\nabla}^2$ operator. For natural boundary conditions, it is just a Fourier transform.

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier transform is?

Comment: @Sunyam thanks for the help, though i still didnt succeed

Comment: @DanielSank i do have some knowledge but not expert